# Cannot read property 'readline' of undefined

Tags: node.js

I'm doing this code, but I not know which is the error

```
var serialport=`require('serialport')`;

var SerialPort=serialport.SerialPort;

var myport = new SerialPort("COM3",{
    baudrate:9600,
    parser:serialport.parsers.readline("\n")
});

myport.open("open",function() {
    console.log("Puerto serie abierto");
    });

myport.on("data",function(datos){

console.log(datos);
});
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are the backticks around `require('serialport')` actually in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
var serialport=`require('serialport')`;
```

with

```
var serialport=require('serialport');
```

Notice the removal of `'` around `require('serialport')`